# Can we repush/reupload sonarqube analysis to server?

Tags: sonarqube

Is there a way to re-push sonar analysis to server. 
My sonar project analysis runs for around 2 hrs and once its pushed to server its failing on server processing. Sonar analysis itself is succesful but its failing on server processing. I am using LTS 6.7.2 version
I have to rerun the analysis again for 2 hours to push results to server

Thanks,
Pavan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible to upload an analysis report that was previously generated.